# Continuous function of CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making an app with a function to start a `Timer`. However I am facing a very serious problem.

Now suppose I have stared the timer of `10 minutes` using `CountDownTimer`. After 10 minutes it should give me a beep. Now suppose I have pressed the home button thus making an application go on background. `CountDownTimer` property is that it continues to countDown, thus after 10 minutes I will get a `beep`.

However this happens if the screen time is not out. If the `screen time is out` and the screen goes blank/black then the timer still continues but at its finish, nothing in the application runs like app is on pause and once i click any button on mobile to make the mobile active, the application starts running in the background again..

I want to stop this and want the app to run even the screen time is out too.

How can this be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to get a [partial wakelock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) to keep the CPU running , so that your timer continues to run. Otherwise the device goes to sleep.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Countdown");
 wl.acquire();
```

In finish you can do a release.

```
 wl.release();
```

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I was trying something similar and in my case the timer still stops working if you place the application in the background (press home and open another app and then switch the screen off). I acquire a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK but OnPause and OnStop are both hit and the CountDownTimer stops. Anything I should be on the look-out for?

Comment: where are you releasing the wakelock? onpause and onstop will not stop hitting if you acquire a wakelock

Comment: Releasing the wakelock onPause and onFinish (which ever happens first).

Comment: release should be done in onfinish of CountdownTimer. Phone will be awake till timer expires. If expiration time is high, then it is better to go with AlarmManager with WAKEUP flag

Comment: Thanks for the help. Going to check-out AlarmManager. Only releasing wakelock onFinish but even with an expiration of only 3 minutes, if focus changes to another app and the screen is switched off the timer stops.

Comment: Just for interest. I tried it on HTC with Adroid 2.3.5 and PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK works but on Samsung Galaxy S III with 4.1.2, it doesn't work when focus changes to another app and the screen is switched off. Going to see if it's 4.1.2 or Samsung Galaxy S III that makes the difference.